# Multiple addresses in rails geocoder issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I have a booking model with location_pickup and location_dropoff on which i want to use the geocoder feature. I have declared the geocoder mapping in the model (below), but somehow only the last declaration(location_pickup) is getting updated in the database. Anything specific I am doing wrong here?

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

geocoded_by :location_dropoff, :latitude => :location_dropoff_latitude,   :longitude => :location_dropoff_longitude

geocoded_by :location_pickup, :latitude => :location_pickup_latitude, :longitude => :location_pickup_longitude

after_validation :geocode, if: :location_dropoff_changed?
after_validation :geocode, if: :location_pickup_changed?

validates :location_pickup, presence: true
validates :location_dropoff, presence: true
end
```

**Tried defining two methods as suggested by Lorenzo but it still does not work**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :geocode_location_dropoff
  before_validation :geocode_location_pickup
  belongs_to :user
     def geocode_location_dropoff
        geocoded_by :location_dropoff, 
          latitude: :location_dropoff_latitude, 
          longitude: :location_dropoff_longitude
      end
      def geocode_location_pickup
        geocoded_by :location_pickup, 
          latitude: :location_pickup_latitude, 
          longitude: :location_pickup_longitude
      end

      after_validation :geocode, if: :location_dropoff_changed?
      after_validation :geocode, if: :location_pickup_changed?

      validates :location_pickup, presence: true
      validates :location_dropoff, presence: true
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling geocoded_by the second time you redefine the method geocoded_by in your model. What you are doing equals pretty much the following:

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

And as you can imagine if you call 'a' it will only have the value '2'. If you want your model to geocode multiple 'things' I would suggest you to create 2 different classes (one is called LocationDropoff and the other LocationPickup) so that you can geocode them independently and make them belong to the Booking class. Otherwise you should define your own methods to geolocate independently different attributes and you could use callbacks for that.

Comment: Thanks! how to define my own method and geolocate independently. I created two different methods and tried to validate them before. Its not working though (added the tired code to the question)